# Detect if beautifulsoup found text on a page or not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup.body.findAll(text='No Results Found')
```

basically I need something that goes like

```
if soup.body.findAll(text='No Results Found') does find this text:
   print("URL doesn't exist")
```

really hope this isn't a stupid question but I'm not sure what to look up to find the answer to this if it's been asked already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup.body.findAll(text='No Results Found')` searches for elements that have the exact text 'No Results Found'.

But I think that your problem does not need `beautifulsoup` at all. To see if the string 'No Results Found' is located on the page you just should try to find your string in the HTML:

```
import requests

html = requests.get(your_url)
if 'No Results Found' in html:
    print("URL doesn't exist")
```